# How can multiple threads execute same method in parallel?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, jvm

I stuck on this question while reading [this](https://medium.com/@hasanli.vusala.73/how-does-singleton-bean-serve-multiple-requests-at-the-same-time-in-spring-f4c9d797dec9) article about how Spring singleton, stateless bean serve multiple requests.
This is the main author point of how it is done:

> When the thread request the singleton bean, it is going to refer (with help of reference variable in stack) to the bytecode of singleton bean in heap. So multiple threads can refer singleton bean at the same time. The compiler is going to point to the same bytecode and simply execute it and store method specific values in corresponding blocks in stack separately.

Good article but it missing some crucial details about how exactly bytecode is executed by threads. My undestanding: Each thread has it own stack, stack contains frames, frames contains return values, local variables, operand stack and Current Class Constant Pool Reference. All classes ale loaded to Method Area, where each Class Data store constants and method code. So we have method code ONLY in one place. Thus, one line of method(which is later is bytecode in JVM) could be executed only by one thread at one core of CPU. Execution of same line of method cannot be performed at same time by two different threads on two different cores. But two DIFFERENT lines of code in method can be executed simultaneously by two different threads on two different cores. And each of thread can start execute method if no other thread executing first line of method.

Comment: But what about simultaneous execution of line of code by two threads on different cores? Is it still possible? Or you mean each threads read instruction from shared bytecode into own frame and then execute it with own local variables?

Comment: The code doesn’t change. There is never a problem with multiple threads reading something that doesn’t change. You can also use the same classes in multiple JVMs at the same time, as the JVMs will also only read the class or jar files.

Answer (score 0):

> So we have method code ONLY in one place.

Yes.

> Thus, one line of method(which is later is bytecode in JVM) could be executed only by one thread at one core of CPU.

This is incorrect.  Program memory is shared by all threads and this includes the classes and byte-code.  Classes are locked when they are *loaded* but not when being executed or referenced without specific synchronization primitives being used.

> Execution of same line of method cannot be performed at same time by two different threads on two different cores.

There is nothing that enforces this restriction.

> And each of thread can start execute method if no other thread executing first line of method.

This is *only* true if a method is marked as `synchronized` and two threads are locking on the same object instance or if the method is static.  See the following pseudo code.

```
public class Foo {
   // many threads can be running bar() concurrently
   public void bar() {
      ...
   }

   // threads that are using the same instance of Foo can only execute
   // synchronized baz() and other synchronized methods one at a time.
   // Threads using other instances can execute baz() concurrently
   public synchronized void baz() {
      ...
   }

   // threads that are in the same classloader can only execute static
   // synchronized bing() and other static synchronized methods one at a time
   // because the class is being synchronized
   public static synchronized void bing() {
      ...
   }
}
```

This does not address memory sharing, message passing, or the other complex concepts involved with threaded programming.